# Not able to run a custom daemontool service

Tags: linux, supervisord, daemontools

I created a service to run my web application but I was not able to  as it  gave me a **exec format error.**

My run file in
**/services/chatery/run which is linked in /service/**

```
exec '/home/ubuntu/chattery/chatery/app.py --host 10.0.0.14 --port 80 --tz Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
```

when I try to run.

```
root@ip-10-0-0-14:/# svscan service
supervise: fatal: unable to start chatery/run: exec format error
supervise: fatal: unable to start chatery/run: exec format error
supervise: fatal: unable to start chatery/run: exec format error
```

Comment: Any reason you are running this with exec?

Comment: I tried using exec because without using exec, if i put just the command it gives me the same error.
  `supervise: fatal: unable to start chatery/run: exec format error`